# How to copy files from a different linux server folder to Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have multiple files in a  different linux server folder and I want to create a cron job and run daily in kubernetes that should copy the files to a pod network folder.

I am researching a lot on this, but non of them gave a me clue to do this experiment. Is it we need to create Persistent volume claim against linux folder? Please help to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple files in a different linux server folder and I want to create a cron job and run daily in kubernetes that should copy the files to a pod network folder.

I am unaware how to perform the task as you have stated.

How to solve your problem? With the belief your "POD network folder" is a SMB, NFS, other type mounted resource;

I would implement one of the following, either will work the same in the end:

1. Establish a connection directly from the Linux Host (that presently has the file(s) to be copied) to the Networked Folder. Use SCP or Rsync to perform the copy.
2. Using SCP or Rsync copy the file(s) directly from the Linux Host homing the files to the IP Address of the POD. Given the POD has a standing connection to the Hosted Folder. e.g. NFS, SMB, other mount.

Comment: I am looking for #2 option and I want to create a cron job that have to done daily. could you give me some examples? to access hosted folder in kubernetes do we need to create pvc ?